# How can I remove or overwrite the YAML validation from a Webform Entity?

Tags: webforms

I am currently building a module that parses raw HTML into a webform using YAML, however I am running into an issue where the `name='SomeName'` on form elements is causing an error in the YAML keys.

The form relies on the name attribute in order to accurately map the data so I need it to be case insensitive.  I can force a save programmatically with

```php
$webform = new \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::create(
// stuff here
);

$webform->save();
```

However when someone attempts to edit the form in the UI and saves, there is an error preventing save that comes from `docroot/modules/contrib/webform/src/WebformEntityElementsValidator.php`

This error prevents saving due to casing errors.
[image: The element key contact_Name on line 1 must contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.]

`The element key contact_Name on line 1 must contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.`

I have tried

```php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $forms_array = ['webform_ui_element_form', 'webform_source_form'];
  if (in_array($form_id, $forms_array)) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = [];
    $form['actions']['submit']['#_validate_form'] = FALSE;
  }

}
```

However it seems that for some reason this prevents saving a new element.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is coming \Drupal\webform\WebformEntityElementsValidator. You would need to override this service and remove the validation rule.

Comment: This is what I've been missing.  I don't know why I couldn't figure it out before.  Thank you!

Comment: I just learned how to use service decorators. This is might be the best approach to tweaking/altering the WebformEntityElementsValidator service. https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-symfony-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this, thanks to some guidance in the comments, by overriding a service.

This involved work in two custom module files.  The first was modules/custom/mymodule/src/MymoduleFormParserServiceProvider.php

Within that file I used `::alter` to alter which class is called for a particular service.

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * Replace Webform validator service.
 */
class MymoduleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase implements ServiceProviderInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('webform.elements_validator');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\mymodule\MymoduleWebformElementsValidator');
  }

}
```

What this does is tell Drupal that when the `webform.elements_validator` service is called, use the `MymoduleWebformElementsValidator` class instead.

The second piece of the puzzle was to create that class.  I did that by extending the original class `WebformEntityElementsValidator` with my own `MymoduleWebformElementsValidator` class and doing the logic there.  That way I was able to keep most of the validation from the original, but make the changes to the validate method that were needed.

I was able to find many of the answers after googling override service thanks to the comment on the question by @jrockowitz